# How can I deduce my RPG lags for better performance?

Tags: javascript, rpg, lag

Okay, so I've started making a game using Khan Academy's Processing JavaScript, and I'm trying to delag it a bit since the framerate is very shaky. So, I've taken the advice of someone, and they told me instead of `new object_name()`, I could instead use something like `object_name.create()` by having this code:

```
Object.constructor.prototype.create = function() {
    var obj = Object.create(this.prototype);
    this.apply(obj, arguments);
    return obj;
};
```

So, I'm assuming it's helping since the framerate improved a bit, but not at all that much. I've been using a lot of OOP, and people have told me that Khan Academy's memory is acting weird, so it's not as good to use OOP, but I'm used to using it, so I'd like to see what kind of things there could be to help improve my program in framerate. I'm planning to check if the NPCs and enemies are in range, then draw them, but I'm not sure if this would help, because I'm not very familiar with the computers and how fast they would run certain things. Thank you.

For reference, this is my game [Quests of a Warrior](https://www.khanacademy.org/computer-programming/quests-of-a-warrior/6704283260502016?width=700&height=700)

This is the comment that someone posted that I happened to see, and that's why I used the `object_name.create()` for now. [Discussion post (expand_key will lead you there)](https://www.khanacademy.org/computer-programming/drones/4696893828317184?qa_expand_key=ag5zfmtoYW4tYWNhZGVteXJpCxIIVXNlckRhdGEiRnVzZXJfaWRfa2V5X2h0dHA6Ly9pZC5raGFuYWNhZGVteS5vcmcvNTQzYTYwMmM4ZTQxNGNmMmJhYjJiNzhiNzQ1MWRkYzkMCxIIRmVlZGJhY2sYgIC9sauorAgM)

If you are unfamiliar with Processing JavaScript, you can go to the documentation, although it doesn't include much (Khan Academy version). You'll find it [here](https://www.khanacademy.org/computing/computer-programming/pjs-documentation), but you can also glance at the real Processing JavaScript (notice that some can't be used for Khan Academy purposes) [here](https://processing.org/reference/)

**EDIT**: I've figured out that you can do object pooling! The method shown [here](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/speed/static-mem-pools/) uses `gEntityObjectPool`. Is this in pure JavaScript?

Comment: If you think you have issues with "creating objects", I would probably look at _how many objects_ you create (or your creation pattern), rather than how you create the object.

Comment: There are about a hundred tips one can give regarding how to improve the performance of a JavaScript application. This makes this question far too broad for the format of this website. But if Khan Academy didn't tell you about the JavaScript Profiler included in most web browsers, then I would recommend you to familiarize yourself with it. Because it can tell you which parts of your game's code are the real performance killers.

Comment: @Vaillancourt, I've been using LOTS of objects.

Comment: @Philipp , where can I start to learn that, though?

Comment: @Potato https://letmegooglethat.com/?q=JavaScript+Profiler+Tutorial

Comment: If you create and destroy a lot of objects often, you might want to check the concept of object pooling. If you have lots of objects, all the time, maybe you have too many, period, and you need to review your game design (you'll need to profile).

Comment: Oh, okay. I'll try and dive more into profiling then. Is there really any difference between OOP and arrays to simulate OOP?

Comment: Welcome to GDSE. I'm voting to close under "needs focus" as asking about 'what constitutes OPP' & 'how to improve performance' are two very different topics. That said, the performance aspect is also a very broad topic in itself and that part alone would benefit from additional information / code. For instance, what objects are creating & how are often are you doing so? Try to summarize the problem; SE questions are intended to be largely self contained & few users here are going to go to another site & read through your entire source code in an attempt to find the problem.

Comment: @Potato That is called a "structure of arrays" and is completely separate from OOP.